# javax jws deploy Cannot obtain endpoint

Tags: java, web-services, openshift

I did write a simple java web service (using javax jws). I am trying to deploy this service into Jboss server at openshift. When I am trying to access the service I am receiving the exception above.

### Java Service Interface:

```
@PermitAll
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface CalWebService {
    @WebMethod int add(int x, int y);
}
```

### Java Service Implementation:

```
@PermitAll
@WebService(
endpointInterface="cmps.CalWebService",
portName="CalWebServicePort",
serviceName="CalWebService")
public class CalWebServiceImp implements CalWebService {
    @Override
    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

### Exception: http://cmps-mohamadjaber.rhcloud.com/CalWebService

HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet cmps.CalWebServiceImp threw exception
    org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
root cause

javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Cannot obtain endpoint for: jboss.ws:context=,endpoint=cmps.CalWebServiceImp
    org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.initServiceEndpoint(ServletHelper.java:108)
    org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.initEndpoint(ServletHelper.java:82)
    org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.loadBus(CXFServletExt.java:64)
    org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.init(CXFServletExt.java:58)
    org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.init(WSFServlet.java:57)
    org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the JBoss Web/7.0.13.Final logs.

JBoss Web/7.0.13.Final

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a `jboss-web.xml` file under `WEB-INF`
with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jboss-web>
        <context-root>/</context-root>
    </jboss-web>
```

as explained here:
[openshift - how to obtain webservice endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26702300/openshift-how-to-obtain-webservice-endpoint)