# openshift - how to obtain webservice endpoint

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, wsdl, openshift

I've created a sample web service as

```
package com.faisal.webservices.register;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService()
public class RegisterService {

    @WebMethod()
    public String sayHello(String name) {
        System.out.println("Hello: " + name);
        return "Hello " + name + "!";
    }
}
```

*web.xml*

```
<servlet>
    <display-name>RegisterService</display-name>
    <servlet-name>RegisterService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.faisal.webservices.register.RegisterService</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RegisterService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/RegisterService</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

when I'm trying to access the `wsdl` url `http://osdbconn-faisal.rhcloud.com/RegisterService?WSDL` (as [mentioned here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Developer_Studio/6.0/html/JBoss_SOAP_Web_Services_User_Guide/sample_web_service_wizards.html#sample_web_service_wizards-sample_restful_web_service-generation)) it returned an exception

[image: webservice endpoint exception]

How could I obtain the endpoint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After lot of searching on google [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24316703/725306) pointed me towards `In order to be able to access the WSDL file I had to create a file jboss-web.xml`.
So, I've created `jboss-web.xml` under `WEB-INF` as ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9634141/725306))

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```